# H2 JDBC error when you have a table called "Users"

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, h2

I'm upgrading my library to support H2 baseline 2.0 and I have tests that fail because I have a table called Users, but H2 now seems to see that as it's USERS table in INFORMATION_SCHEMA rather than in PUBLIC.

I tried changing my URL to jdbc:h2:{$home}/pinf;SCHEMA=PUBLIC but I still see 2 copies of USERS. I don't want to see the tables in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

How do I have a user that would only see PUBLIC schema?

This worked fine under H2 1.x.

To clarify this is when using `con.getMetaData().getTables`

I 1st log in as sa then:

```
CREATE USER pinf PASSWORD 'pinf' ADMIN;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA PUBLIC TO pinf;
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA INFORMATION_SCHEMA FROM pinf;
```

then I log in as 'pinf'

iterating across meta data with getTables with null parameters for catalog, schema pattern and table name pattern includes the tables from INFORMATION_SCHEMA. This was not the case in 1.x version.

Comment: @xerx593 The robot gave me a solution that I was working on already. Thanks anyway.

Comment: `USERS` is not a reserved word. (`USER` is.) Where exactly do you see these two tables? `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is visible for everyone, you can't hide it. But it isn't included into schema search path by default.

Comment: Correct, actually not a "reserved word" ..but one of http://www.h2database.com/html/systemtables.html

Comment: `SELECT something FROM USERS` selects rows from `PUBLIC.USERS` table if this table exists, otherwise it throws an exception. `SELECT something FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.USERS` selects rows from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.USERS` system table, you need to qualify names of tables when they don't belong to the current schema or any schema specified with `SCHEMA_SEARCH_PATH` if this setting was used.

Comment: Tip: Append an underscore to every name (table, column, index, etc.) to avoid collision with keywords, reserved words, system names. The SQL standard explicitly promises to never use a trailing underscore.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Unreproducible.

The default schema in H2 is `PUBLIC`. If you create a table there named `USERS`, that table is found by default.

Be aware of your current schema. The standard `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` schema contains a table named `USERS`.

## Not reproducible

As noted in the Comments:

- `USERS` is not a reserved word in H2 Database Engine.
- No table named `USERS` is available by default in H2.
- The default schema in H2 is `PUBLIC`. If you create a table there, and query on that table, it will be found by default.

So the problem raised in your Question is not reproducible.

I suspect you have changed the default schema to the SQL standard schema of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. See the [*System Tables*](http://www.h2database.com/html/systemtables.html#information_schema_users) page in the documentation. There exits a table named `USERS`, [as documented](http://www.h2database.com/html/systemtables.html#information_schema_users).

Here is an example app that makes 3 attempts to query a table named `USERS` in:

- The schema named `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.
- The schema named `PUBLIC`, explicitly.
- The default schema (which is `PUBLIC`, implicitly).

The results are, respectively:

- Success. Table found in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.
- Failure. No such table in `PUBLIC`.
- Failure. No such table in default schema, `PUBLIC`.

Next we create a table named exactly `USERS` in the default schema, `PUBLIC`. And we run our same 3 attempts above.

The results are, respectively:

- Success. Table found in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.
- Success. Table found in `PUBLIC`.
- Success. Table found in default schema, `PUBLIC`.

By the way, the name of the default schema in H2 is defined as a constant: [`Constants.SCHEMA_MAIN`](https://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/engine/Constants.html#SCHEMA_MAIN). That constant holds a value of `PUBLIC` as shown in this example code.

## Example code

```java
package work.basil.example.db;

import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class UsersTableEx
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println ( "org.h2.engine.Constants.SCHEMA_MAIN = " + org.h2.engine.Constants.SCHEMA_MAIN + "\n---------------------" );
        UsersTableEx app = new UsersTableEx ( );
        DataSource dataSource = app.obtainDataSource ( );

        app.queryInformationSchemaUsers ( dataSource );
        app.queryPublicUsers ( dataSource );
        app.queryUsers ( dataSource );

        app.createUsersTable(dataSource );

        app.queryInformationSchemaUsers ( dataSource );
        app.queryPublicUsers ( dataSource );
        app.queryUsers ( dataSource );

        System.out.println ( "INFO - Demo done." );
    }
    
    private void queryInformationSchemaUsers ( DataSource dataSource )
    {
        System.out.println ( "INFO - Query for INFORMATION_SCHEMA.USERS." );
        String sql = """
                SELECT *
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.USERS
                ;
                """;
        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection ( ) ;
                Statement statement = conn.createStatement ( ) ;
        )
        {
            try (
                    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery ( sql ) ;
            )
            {
                while ( resultSet.next ( ) )
                {
                    System.out.println (
                            "USER_NAME = " + resultSet.getString ( "USER_NAME" ) +
                                    " | IS_ADMIN = " + resultSet.getBoolean ( "IS_ADMIN" ) +
                                    " | REMARKS = " + resultSet.getString ( "REMARKS" ) +
                                    "\n------------------"
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        catch ( SQLException e ) { throw new RuntimeException ( e ); }
    }

    private void queryPublicUsers ( DataSource dataSource )
    {
        System.out.println ( "INFO - Query for PUBLIC.USERS." );
        String sql = """
                SELECT *
                FROM PUBLIC.USERS
                ;
                """;
        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection ( ) ;
                Statement statement = conn.createStatement ( ) ;
        )
        {
            try (
                    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery ( sql ) ;
            )
            { while ( resultSet.next ( ) ) System.out.println ( "Found row." ); }
        }
        catch ( org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException e )
        {
            System.out.println ( "ERROR - " + e.getMessage ( ) + "\n--------------" );
        }
        catch ( SQLException e ) { throw new RuntimeException ( e ); }
    }

    private void queryUsers ( DataSource dataSource )
    {
        System.out.println ( "INFO - Query for USERS." );
        String sql = """
                SELECT *
                FROM USERS
                ;
                """;
        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection ( ) ;
                Statement statement = conn.createStatement ( ) ;
        )
        {
            try (
                    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery ( sql ) ;
            )
            { while ( resultSet.next ( ) ) System.out.println ( "Found row." ); }
        }
        catch ( org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException e )
        {
            System.out.println ( "ERROR - " + e.getMessage ( ) + "\n--------------" );
        }
        catch ( SQLException e ) { throw new RuntimeException ( e ); }
    }

    private void createUsersTable ( DataSource dataSource )
    {
        System.out.println ( "INFO - Running `createUsersTable` method. \n-----------------------------" );
        String sql = """
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS
                (
                    user_ TEXT NOT NULL ,
                    id_ UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT RANDOM_UUID() ,
                    CONSTRAINT history_pkey_ PRIMARY KEY ( id_ )
                )
                ;
                """;
        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection ( ) ;
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement ( ) ;
        )
        {
            stmt.executeUpdate ( sql );
        } catch ( SQLException e ) { e.printStackTrace ( ); }
    }

    private DataSource obtainDataSource ( )
    {
        org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource ds = new JdbcDataSource ( );  // An implementation of `javax.sql.DataSource` bundled with H2.
        ds.setURL ( "jdbc:h2:mem:users_mystery_db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" );
        ds.setUser ( "scott" );
        ds.setPassword ( "tiger" );
        ds.setDescription ( "An example database showing a query for table named `USERS`." );
        return ds;
    }
}
```

When run:

```
org.h2.engine.Constants.SCHEMA_MAIN = PUBLIC
---------------------
INFO - Query for INFORMATION_SCHEMA.USERS.
USER_NAME = SCOTT | IS_ADMIN = true | REMARKS = null
------------------
INFO - Query for PUBLIC.USERS.
ERROR - Table "USERS" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
SELECT *
FROM PUBLIC.USERS
;
 [42104-214]
--------------
INFO - Query for USERS.
ERROR - Table "USERS" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
SELECT *
FROM USERS
;
 [42104-214]
--------------
INFO - Running `createUsersTable` method. 
-----------------------------
INFO - Query for INFORMATION_SCHEMA.USERS.
USER_NAME = SCOTT | IS_ADMIN = true | REMARKS = null
------------------
INFO - Query for PUBLIC.USERS.
INFO - Query for USERS.
INFO - Demo done.
```

## Trailing underscore avoids collisions

Tip: Append an underscore to every name (table, column, index, etc.) to avoid collision with keywords, reserved words, system names.

The SQL standard explicitly promises to never use a trailing underscore in any of its names, keywords, reserved words, system tables, and such.

Comment: Thanks.   The actual place that causes the issue is when iterating over con.getMetaData().getTables().  The parameter for schema pattern - when null I thought should only find tables that the user has permission for. Usually that's what happens. In H2 as of V2 it seems we'll get the ones in INFORMATION_SCHEMA as well.

Comment: @sproketboy Your expectations disagree with the JDBC specification. The Javadoc for [`DatabaseMetaData#getTables`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String%5B%5D)) says nothing about filtering the results by user permissions. The Javadoc does mention that “Note: Some databases may not return information for all tables.” but gives no further explanation.

Comment: Whatever you say. It works fine using PUBLIC for schema pattern so it's fine for my purposes.